# IPython Pylab Configuration - imshow interpolation

Tags: python, configuration, matplotlib, ipython

I have been working with IPython for several months now and I think it is one of the best interactive shells I've used.  I especially like the built in matplotlib support through pylab.

One issue I have had is that I am working with image analysis and often plot images and other arrays using imshow.  When using pure matplotlib, I have the ability to set the default interpolation as `nearest` using the matplotlibrc file.  I have not been able to find such a file for the built in matplotlib in IPython.

Is there a way to configure IPython and Pylab to use `nearest` interpolation by default instead of `bilinear`?  I have read the IPython documentation regarding configuration and customization and I'm not sure I follow how to access such specific properties.

Comment: matplotlib loads matplotlibrc just the same when invoked from IPython as not.  What backend are you using (`matplotlib.backends.backend`)?

Comment: I'm using the default backend, which is apparently `TkAgg`.

Comment: what is `pylab.rcParams['image.interpolation']` in each context?

Comment: if there does not exist a `matplotlibrc`, it will just use the defaults.  You may need to create the file.